# Error creating dataframes in spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I am trying to create a dataframe  in kafka-spark stream , i have successfuly mapped values to case class, but whenever i call toDF method it gives me  error.
 **

> value toDF is not a member of Array[WeatherEvent] [error] possible
>   cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'? [error]
>   }).toDF("longitude", "latitude", "country", "sunrise", "sunset",
>   "temperature", "temperatureMin", "temperatureMax",  [error]          ^
>   [error] one error found [error] (compile:compileIncremental)
>   Compilation failed [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Sep 27, 2017
>   11:49:23 AM

Here is my code

```
 val inputStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, PreferConsistent, Subscribe[String, String ](Array("test"), kafkaParams))
 //  val json = parse(inputStream)


  val processedStream = inputStream
  .flatMap(record => record.value.split(" ").map(payload => {
        //val ts = Timestamp.valueOf(payload(3))
        WeatherEvent(payload(0).toDouble, payload(1).toDouble, payload(2).toString , payload(3).toInt,
                    payload(4).toInt, payload(5).toDouble, payload(6).toDouble, payload(7).toDouble, 
                    payload(8).toDouble, payload(9).toInt, payload(10).toInt, payload(11).toInt, 
                    payload(12).toDouble, payload(13).toDouble)
      }).toDF("longitude", "latitude", "country", "sunrise", "sunset", "temperature", "temperatureMin", "temperatureMax", 
              "pressure", "humidity", "cloudiness", "id", "wind_speed", "wind_deg")
 )
```

Thanks **

Comment: I guess WeatherEvent is a case class. if thats correct then you don't need to give header names in toDF, Just doing .toDF is enough.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan thanks, but its still same.
 value toDF is not a member of Array[WeatherEvent]
[error] possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value toDF'?
[error]       }).toDF()
[error]          ^
[error] one error found

Comment: @matesio can you try importing this `import ssc.implicits._`

Comment: yes exactly. I agree with Akash that you need implicits._ to be imported to apply .toDF

Comment: yeah i tried 
**    val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.implicits._  **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

toDF() is an implicit method defined in sqlContext. toDF() is used to convert an RDD to Dataframe. Here you are getting a stream from Kafka I mean Dstreams. To convert the same to DF, you need to process each RDD in the Dstreams either using **transform** API or **foreachRDD** API. Below I am using foreachRDD transformation to convert RDD to Dataframe

```
val data=KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "GroupName", topics).map(x=>x._2)
val lines12=data.foreachRDD(x=>{
  val df=x.flatMap(x => x.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0),x(1))).toDF()
}
```